# In Text area onchange value is not populating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

```
 <textarea className="form-control queryheight box_xp" placeholder="Enter Dashboard Content" type="text" onChange={this.dashboardtextchartchange.bind(this)} value={this.state.textdashboard}>
    </textarea>
```

Onchange function :

```
dashboardtextchartchange(e){
this.setState({textdashboard: e.target.value});
}
```

State:

```
    this.state = {
       textdashboard: '',

    };
```

If i remove `value={this.state.textdashboard}` then working fine, But if i keep this its not coming

Comment: I checked your code in my local machine and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea does not have a `value` attribute, hence why it only works when you remove it.

You can set the value of a `<textarea>` by entering the desired value in between the opening and closing tags, `<textarea>[here]</textarea>`.

```
<textarea className="form-control queryheight box_xp" placeholder="Enter Dashboard Content" type="text" onChange={this.dashboardtextchartchange.bind(this)}>
    {this.state.textdashboard}
</textarea>
```

You may also want to remove your `type="text"` attribute, too, as textarea does not have a type attribute.

Comment: OP code works fine. React provides us to use the value even in textarea. Just verified by testing in local machine and also saw in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag).

Comment: Ewww, really?! I bet that causes confusion over time. Thanks for pointing that out.